# Inserting data into MySQL database (no data)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save values in the database by using php, I got no error, but the database is empty it is not saved the data.

I put if statements to check if the value saved before

please check my code

please help me

```
<?php
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
$sid  = strip_tags($_POST['sid']);
$Desc = strip_tags($_POST['Desc']);    
if ($submit) {
    // open data base
    $connet = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "hahaha1");
    mysql_select_db("senior");        
    $sensorcheck = mysql_query("SELECT sid FROM availblesensors WHERE sid='$sid'");
    $count       = mysql_num_rows($sensorcheck);
    if ($count != 0) {
        die("You add this Sensor ID before!");
    }        
    if ($sid && $Desc) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO availblesensors ('$sid','$Desc')");
        // success 
        die("You have add new sensor Successfully !! <a href='admin.php'>click here to return to admin page</a> or Here to
 <a href='gotoaddsensor.php'>add new sensor</a>");
    } else {
        echo "<h3><font color='red'>Please fill in <b>all</b> feilds!</font></h3>";
    }        
}
?>




<form action="gotoaddsensor.php" method="post" class="one">

<div class="info">

    <center><div>Please add availble sensors with a few description of it if you need</div></center><br/>
</div>


                <div><b><label for="sid">Sensor ID</label>:</b>
                <input name="sid" value="" id="sid" type="text" size="15"/> </div>
    <br />
                <div><b><label for="password">Description</label>:</b>
                <input name="Desc" value="" id="Desc" type="text" size="40"/></div>
    <br />

            <div id="login-button">
            <input  name="submit"  type="submit" value="submit"  />
                            <input type="reset" value="clear" />
 </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: add `or die(mysql_error());` to the end of your insert line and see if it raises an error.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Comment: check the query in the mysql log, if you try to run the query from the mysql console it will probably fail

Comment: Remember that you shoul always escape values before you use them in queries. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

The query will be

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO availblesensors VALUES ('$sid','$Desc')");
```

not

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO availblesensors ('$sid','$Desc')");`
```

You missed `VALUES` keyword in query.

Comment: @SaraSayyar If you found the answer useful then mark the answer as correct so other users can refer the answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

your sql sentence is wrong..

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO availblesensors ('$sid','$Desc')");
```

you're saying that $id and $Desc are columns in availablesensors, you should add VALUES before the actual values

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO availblesensors VALUES ('$sid','$Desc')");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a little mistake in code. Change by below code.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO availblesensors ('$sid','$Desc')");
```

Replaced by

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO availblesensors values ("'.$sid.'","'.$Desc.'")");
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i forgot to write "values" word, like this mysql_query("INSERT INTO availblesensors VALUES('$sid','$Desc')")

Answer (score 0):

Change the lines to this:

```
if ($sid && $Desc) {
    if(!mysql_query("INSERT INTO availblesensors values ('$sid','$Desc')")) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }  
} else {
    echo "<h3><font color='red'>Please fill in <b>all</b> feilds!</font></h3>";
}
```

this way you can see the error it gives you if any

Answer (score 0):

Query should be

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO availblesensors VALUES (' ".$sid." ',' ".$Desc." ')");
```

not

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO availblesensors ('$sid','$Desc')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the required changes

```
$connet = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "hahaha1");
mysql_select_db("senior", $connet);        
$sensorcheck = mysql_query("SELECT sid FROM availblesensors 
                                       WHERE sid='$sid'",$connet);
$count = mysql_num_rows($sensorcheck);
if ($count != 0) {
    die("You add this Sensor ID before!");
}        
if ($sid && $Desc) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO availblesensors ('$sid','$Desc') 
                                       VALUES('Sensor Id','Sensor Desc')", $connet);
```